# Login failed when using custom Grails Spring Security filter

Tags: security, spring, grails, filter

I am using Grails with the Spring Security plugin.

I have crafted a custom filter, authentication provider, and token and registered them as beans and into filter chain:

```
SpringSecurityUtils.clientRegisterFilter('myFilter',SecurityFilterPosition.SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER.order + 10)
```

(I am not really sure what the order should be)

I POST to `j_spring_security_check`.

All seems to run smoothly to my successfulAuthentication where I set:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);
```

with no errors and `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` is set.

However Grails redirects me to login failed page.

Is something wrong with the `j_spring_security_check` page? Where is the error?

Comment: It sounds like there might be an issue with your `AuthenticationProvider` or `Filter`; perhaps you can post some of their code?

Comment: or with a Authentication token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the url j_spring_security_check - it somehow rewrote the security context.
So on using custom filters **DO NOT** use post url "j_spring_security_check", not necessary also.